# WooCommerce email notification option when product is back in stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have made a plugin for give notification option when product back in stock , I have made with 2 email sending option one when customer subscribe this option and the second one when product back in stock but this code is sending only first email not back to stock email

code is

```
  function woocommerce_stock_notifier_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('woocommerce-stock-notifier-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);

    wp_localize_script('woocommerce-stock-notifier-script', 'stock_notifier_ajax', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woocommerce_stock_notifier_enqueue_scripts');

// Display notification form on product pages
function woocommerce_stock_notifier_display_form() {
    if (is_product() && !is_user_logged_in()) {
        global $product;
        if (!$product->is_in_stock()) {
            include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/notification-form.php');
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_stock_notifier_display_form', 30);

// Handle form submission
function woocommerce_stock_notifier_handle_submission() {
    if (isset($_POST['product_id']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $product_id = intval($_POST['product_id']);
        $email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);

        // Send email to confirm subscription
        send_subscription_confirmation_email($product_id, $email);

        // Store the email and product ID for notification
        save_notification_data($product_id, $email);

        echo 'You will be notified when the product is back in stock.';
    }
    wp_die(); // Terminate the Ajax request
}
add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_stock_notifier_submit', 'woocommerce_stock_notifier_handle_submission');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_stock_notifier_submit', 'woocommerce_stock_notifier_handle_submission');

// Save notification data to the database
function save_notification_data($product_id, $email) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'stock_notifier_notifications';

    $wpdb->insert(
        $table_name,
        array(
            'product_id' => $product_id,
            'email' => $email,
        ),
        array('%d', '%s')
    );
}

// Send email to confirm subscription
function send_subscription_confirmation_email($product_id, $email) {
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $product_name = $product->get_name();

    $subject = 'Subscription Confirmation';
    $message = "Hello,\n\nYou have subscribed to receive notifications for the product '$product_name' when it is back in stock.";

    wp_mail($email, $subject, $message);
}

// Hook into WooCommerce stock status changes
function woocommerce_stock_notifier_track_stock_status_changes($product_id, $stock_status_transition) {
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

    if ($stock_status_transition['old_status'] !== 'instock' && $stock_status_transition['new_status'] === 'instock' && !$product->managing_stock() && $product->get_stock_quantity() > 0) {
        $notification_data = get_notification_data_by_product_id($product_id);
        if (!empty($notification_data)) {
            foreach ($notification_data as $notification) {
                send_notification_email($product_id, $notification['email']);
            }
            // After sending emails, remove the notification entries for this product
            delete_notification_entries($product_id);
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_set_stock', 'woocommerce_stock_notifier_track_stock_status_changes', 10, 2);

// Send email notification
function send_notification_email($product_id, $email) {
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $product_name = $product->get_name();

    $subject = 'Product Back in Stock Notification';
    $message = "Hello,\n\nThe product '$product_name' is back in stock. Thank you for using our notification service.";

    wp_mail($email, $subject, $message);
}

// Delete notification entries for a product
function delete_notification_entries($product_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'stock_notifier_notifications';

    $wpdb->delete(
        $table_name,
        array('product_id' => $product_id),
        array('%d')
    );
}

// Create database table on plugin activation
function create_notification_table() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'stock_notifier_notifications';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        product_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
        email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'create_notification_table');
?>
```

I wanted to send both emails to the customer tell me how this will work